# TFS lost merge history after moving the branches

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have two branches as below.

```
TeamProject1
    Branch-1
    Branch-2
```

There were some changesets pending to be merged to Branch-1 to Branch-2.
I moved these branches to another TeamProject as below.

```
TeamProject1
   =>
   =>
TeamProject2
   Branch-1
   Branch-2
```

Now am not able to see those previous changesets which were there previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we move TFS branch history gets lost. One should use Team Foundation Server Integration Tools  to retain the history. Though even if you use TFS Integration tool labels gets deleted too.

Comment: It will be great, if you could provide me with some references or pointers.